# Keep special character in sed

Tags: shell, sed, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to pass a string containing special character in sed.

How to escape "$" character?

```
echo "$azerty$" | sed 's///g'
```

Comment: First thing you should check that your shell is really echo'ing `$azerty$` and not trying to expand an `azerty` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "\$azerty$" | sed 's/\$/X/g'
XazertyX
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it for me (using GNU sed)

```
% echo "\$azerty\$" | sed -r -e 's/\$//g'
azerty
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes if you want to disable variable interpolation:

```
$ echo '$azerty$' | sed 's/\$/X/g'
XazertyX
```